# How to collect data of Google Search with beautiful soup using python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to know about how I can collect all the URL's and from the page source using beautiful soup and can visit all of them one by one in the google search results and move to next google index pages.

here is the URL https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.rashmi.com&rct=j that I want to collect and screen shot here http://www.rashmi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/screencapture-www-google-com-search-1433026719960.png

here is the code I'm trying

```
def getPageLinks(page):
links = []
for link in page.find_all('a'):
    url = link.get('href')
    if url:
        if 'www.rashmi.com/' in url:
            links.append(url)
return links

def Links(url):
pUrl = urlparse(url)
return parse_qs(pUrl.query)[0]

def PagesVisit(browser, printInfo):
pageIndex = 1
visited = []
time.sleep(5)
while True:  
    browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.rashmi.com&ei=50hqVdCqJozEogS7uoKADg" + str(pageIndex)+"&start=10&sa=N")
    pList = []
    count = 0

    pageIndex += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

```
def getPageLinks(page):
links = []
for link in page.find_all('a'):
url = link.get('href')
if url:
    if 'www.rashmi.com/' in url:
        links.append(url)
return links

def Links(url):
pUrl = urlparse(url)
return parse_qs(pUrl.query)

def PagesVisit(browser, printInfo):
    start = 0
    visited = []
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:  
            browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.rashmi.com&ei=V896VdiLEcPmUsK7gdAH&" + str(start) + "&sa=N")


    pList = []
    count = 0
    # Random sleep to make sure everything loads
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)


    start +=10      
    if start ==500:
    browser.close()
```